# how to print json response in a tableview using swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, post

this is how im saving response

```
var requests:[[String:Any]] = [[String:Any]] ()
switch response.result {
                        case .success:
                            if let responseValue = response.value as! [String:Any]? {
                            if let responseData = responseValue["data"] as! [[String:Any]]?{
                            self.requests = responseData
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                             }
                          }
```

this is how im saving response data to tableview cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FriendRequestTVC
    let  userData = self.requests[indexPath.row]
    cell.name?.text = (userData["email"] as? String) ?? "No NAME"
    cell.number?.text = (userData["name"] as? String) ?? "No EMAIL"
    return cell
}
```

and this is the response which im trying to save

```
{
"status": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "created_at": "2020-08-05T00:53:58.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-05T00:53:58.000000Z",
        "user": {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "bilal mughal",
            "email": "bilal@123.com",
        }
    },
],
```

}

if I save **created_at & updated_at** values in to labels they will be saved but not inside the values of **user** dictionary

Comment: `let data. = self.requests[indexPath.row]; let userData = data["user"] as? [String: Any]` instead of `let  userData = self.requests[indexPath.row]`, but I would strongly recommend to use custom model with custom structs instead of dictionaries/array and recommend Codable in Swift 4+.

Comment: Thanks man. And I will follow what you suggested